# Oracle SQL error "missing expression" (but same SQL query works in MySQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an existing large enterprise application that we are converting the database from MySQL to Oracle for various reasons. We've got hundreds of current MySQL commands working inside Oracle without much hassle, except for one. The following SQL executes on MySQL without any issues:

```sql
SELECT `user_id`, `shift_type`, `date`, COUNT(*) as c
FROM `staff`
WHERE `date` = '2020-02-02' AND `shift_type` != 'oncall'
GROUP BY user_id, shift_type, date
HAVING c > 1
```

This executes and gives us the results of any staff who exist more than once for a given date with the criteria above. But running that same SQL query in Oracle, with the apostrophes removed (as required by Oracle), we get a `Error Message : ORA-00936: missing expression`. This is the exact Oracle SQL I tried:

```sql
SELECT user_id, shift_type, date, COUNT(*) as c
FROM staff
WHERE date = '2020-02-02' AND shift_type != 'oncall'
GROUP BY user_id, shift_type, date
HAVING c > 1
```

I've checked lots of other Stack Overflow answers about this error code. Most refer to removing an extra comma. I've tried that on various parts above, but nothing seems to work. Really hoping someone here is able to help point me in the right direction.

Comment: "*with the apostrophes removed (as required by Oracle)*" - as required by the SQL standard, this is not Oracle specific. The dreaded backticks are simply invalid standard SQL.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - the backticks come from the ORM we are using, but good to know. The ORM does not seem to generate the backticks in the Oracle query, so thats an improvement :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper syntax  - `"date"` instead  of `date` and `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`:

```
SELECT user_id, shift_type, "date", COUNT(*) as c
FROM staff
WHERE "date" = '2020-02-02' 
  AND shift_type != 'oncall'
GROUP BY user_id, shift_type, "date"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle.com demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f839caafe69faa7bc1000beb6f3442d8)

---

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Oracle expects date literal here, thus error:

```
SELECT date '2020-01-01'
FROM dual
```

Also using keywords as identifiers is not the best practice.

Comment: It probably needs to be `"DATE"` as Oracle stores identifiers as uppercase by default.

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda - that works.

I agree "date" is not best practice, its a legacy application, so I dont think I can change it now. But we'll keep it in mind. I'll flick you the bounty when SO allows me. cheers.

Comment: DATE is a keyword in (all) SQL dialects and namely in ISO SQL. This can easily stop working in future MySQL release too.